# Show that $\alpha: G \rightarrow G ,\alpha(g)=g^2$ isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ be a group and $\alpha: G \rightarrow G ,\alpha(g)=g^2$ ,$G$ is abelian group,
$|G|=2n+1$ show that $\alpha$ isomorphism

**Attempt:**

$\alpha (g_1g_2)=(g_1g_2)(g_1g_2)=(g_1g_1)(g_2g_2)$

$\alpha(g_1)\alpha(g_2)=(g_1g_1)(g_2g_2)$

$G$ is abelian $\Rightarrow \alpha$ is homomorphism

Comment: Who don;'t you show us a few more details of your attempt. Have you shown that the map $\alpha$ is a homomorphism? Once you do that, what's needed to prove that it's an *iso*morphism?

Comment: I do not understand your attempt. What is "hom", and why is $G$ this?

Comment: I believe "$G$ is hom" was meant to say "$\alpha$ is a homomorphism"

Comment: @ASKASK Yeah, probably. But still - at least write out the word fully!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have proved that $\alpha$ is an homomorphism, and $|G|$ is finite, it suffices to show that $\alpha$ is 1-to-1, or equivalently, that $Ker(\alpha)=\{1\}$.

But if $\alpha(g)=g^2=1$, and $g\neq 1$ then the order of $g$ is $2$, that is, $\{1,g\}$ is a subgroup, and this is impossible because $2$ does not divide $|G|=2n+1$.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to say why $G$ abelian implies $\alpha$ is a homomorphism. It's not too hard to show that $\alpha$ is an isomorphism.  Since, $G$ is finite, it suffices to show that $\alpha$ is injective.

Let $g\in\ker\alpha$ ($e$ the identity element)

$$\begin{align}
g\in\ker\alpha & \implies g^2=e\\
& \implies g=e\text{ or } |\langle g\rangle|=2.
\end{align}$$

If $g$ has order $2$, $G$ has a subgroup of order $2$ which is impossible because the order of $G$ is odd.  So, $\ker\alpha=\{e\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use Lagrange's theorem to deduce that $G$ has no element of order $2$.